# Install Xubuntu from USB drive on Debian with faulty network connection

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, xubuntu

I have a Debian 9 XFCE system on my personal computer and recently upgraded to Debian 10, which removed all network configurations. After some research and multiple attempts to fix the issue, I still failed.

So I now decided to move to Xubuntu 18.04. Since I don't have internet connection in my laptop, I'll have to download the Xubuntu iso from another windows computer.

**My doubt is:** can I download the Linux installer on windows, with no harm, to then use it on my Debian computer? My wi-fi network is operative, but does the Xubuntu installation on Debian need my computer to have an active wi-fi connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running Windows you can

- download Xubuntu
- check that it matches the md5sum
- create a live USB drive with Xubuntu ([Rufus](https://rufus.ie) is a good tool in Windows for this task).

Then you can boot the computer where you want to install Xubuntu from the live USB drive with Xubuntu. This will work independently of what is installed in the internal drive, and you can

- backup the files that you want to keep
- install Xubuntu. This will overwrite the previous (faulty) operating system with Xubuntu.

It is *not* necessary to have a working internet connection during the installation. If you are lucky, wifi will work directly with a built-in linux driver. If the wifi hardware needs a proprietary driver, it will be much easier, if you can connect to the internet via wire (ethernet) in order to download the necessary wifi driver. This can be done after Xubuntu is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1242546/197910 which explains:

Download Xubuntu's ISO file at https://xubuntu.org/download

Next, check for download errors per https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu .

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on

- [another Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
- [a Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), or
- [a MacOS X machine](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

When it asks you to download third-party items and updates, tell it no, since you don't yet have that connection. Once installation is complete and you can connect to the Internet later, you can add those third-party items, and update as well.